# Iostat list non-existing block device xvdap1

Tags: iostat

Iostat output on my system:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.13    0.02    0.42    0.32    0.10   99.01

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvdap1            1.29        32.67        10.06   27432377    8450380
```

But if we examine `lsblk`, we do not find a device named `xvdap1`:

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 disk /
```

Moreover, `xvdap1` cannot be found in `/dev/`:

```
user@host:~$ ls /dev/xvd*
/dev/xvda1
```

I'm inclined to believe that `xvdap1` is the same as `/dev/xvda1`, but why on earth would they have two different names? It is a problem, because i get partitions which mounted from `/proc/mounts` and there are not describe `xvdap1`, only `xvda1`. And if i pass /dev/xvda1 request to iostat, f.e.:

```
iostat -p /dev/xvda1
```

He nothing output.

Answer (score 1):

xvdap1 *is* xvda1  This seems to be weirdness with how iostat is displaying the devicename. If you run
`iostat -p /dev/xvda1`
and then `iostat` you should see the exact same numbers for the xvdap1 and xvda1 devices:

```
$ iostat -p /dev/xvda1

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvda1             0.26         0.07         2.66     258713   10327556

$ iostat 

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvdap1            0.26         0.07         2.66     258713   10327556
xvdb              0.00         0.00         0.00        684          0
xvdf              0.77         0.10         5.43     403313   21062404
xvdg              0.00         0.00         0.00        684          0
```

Answer (score 0):

While i can't answer **Why**, the behaviour is defined in
https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/master/sysstat.ioconf

in particular a line:

```
202:xvd:*:0:a:16:p:16:Xen Virtual Block Device
```

The description is in the start of a file and goes like this:

```
#  This file gives iostat, sar, and sadf a clue about how to find whole
#  disk devices in /proc/diskstats.
#  partpre:             appended to whole dev before part designator
#                        eg. the p in c0d2p6, decimal formatting implied
#            '*' means none
```